# Pathfinder Acquiring multiple perform, craft, or profession subskills

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

I'm playing my first pathfinder game and am making a bard.  Is it possible for this character to either start (or acquire over time via leveling up) multiple perform sub skills [perform(dance) and later perform(oratory)]?  I can't find anywhere in the rules that allow this and, if so, how quickly.

Making the question a bit more general, the same goes for crafting and profession.

Is the only way to acquire multiple craft or perform skills to multi-class to another class that also has a craft or perform or profession skill allowance?

[Does every specialization of Craft you take get the class skill bonus, or just the first?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19869/pathfinder-craft-as-class-skill) suggests that each rank applied perform/craft/profession can be applied to a new sub skill.  Is that correct?  If so, can I use multiple skill ranks at first level to give my bard character multiple perform sub skills at first level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Like Craft, Knowledge, and Profession, Perform is actually a number
>   of separate skills. You could have several Perform skills, each with
>   its own ranks.

There is no need to multiclass. If you want Perform(Dance) and Perform(Oratory) you spend skill points for each seperately like a new skill. Same class can have both. This applies to all other sub categoried skills like knowledge or craft.

Comment: And this entire comment thread is irrelevant.  @MatthewNajmon, CanCanbek, please don't use comments for discussion and especially for things not on topic.